# send large data between activity vs read data from sqlite which one is more sense?

Tags: android

i have been alway think that send data between activities would be more efficient than read data from sqlite but now i'm wondering if it's really is.

For my case i have a simple app. when an app open i read data(some MB) from sqlite db to main activity and store there to send to to other activity when they need. but when i send bit amount of data (abount ~1MB) my app start to lag about 2-3 second. So i think it would be better to read it from sqlite instead because when i'm reading i can show "loading" and my app would look more smooth. Can you give me some advice?

Comment: why don't you just store the data in a singleton, and use it from both activities?

Comment: Question is why you need more then 1MB data from sql at once ...

Comment: @VladMatvienko you mean store in a mediate class ? Because i'm new in android so i don't know about it :)

Comment: @Selvin it's a file actually. a whole chapter of story is store in sqlite db

Comment: Well a singleton is a widely used design pattern used in OO languages. You can look here for an example: https://gist.github.com/Akayh/5566992

Comment: i understand now. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending large data between activities via Intent extra can cause TransactionTooLargeException. For example, on Android 6.0 and up the limit is 200kB.

You can read your data from database asynchronously to avoid UI freezes, but I suggest you to load data once and cache it.

Answer (score 0):

Loading data using CursorLoader, Custom Adapter and Content Provider is more efficient and spare your main UI thread and phone resources. I suggest reading about them on Android Developers website.